# Does --list.begin() == list.end()?

Tags: c++, iterator, iteration, language-lawyer, stdlist

Does the standard guarantee that

`--list.begin() == list.end()`

always holds and that it infact is a valid operation? (`list` is an instance of `std::list`).

It appears to be the case with at least MSVC 2019.

This would be useful for instance in the following case:

```
for ( auto i = list.begin(); i != list.end(); ++i )
{
  ...
  list.erase(i--);
  ...
}
```

, i.e. when deleting elements while iterating, since `i` may be the beginning of the list. This would also require `++list.end() == list.begin()` to hold; what about that?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220525/discussion-on-question-by-hi-i-love-so-does-list-begin-list-end).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Does the standard guarantee that
>
> ```
> --list.begin() == list.end()
> ```

No, standard does not guarantee that for `std::list` (nor can such guarantee be assumed given a bidirectional iterator). In fact, the behaviour of `--list.begin()` is undefined.

> This would also require ++list.end() == list.begin() to hold; what about that?

Also not guaranteed, and `++list.end()` has undefined behaviour.

---

Standard quote for [language-lawyer]:

> [bidirectional.iterators]
>
> ```
> Expression | Operational   | Assertion/note
>            | semantics     | pre-/post-condition
> ---------------------------------------------------------
> --r        |               | Preconditions:
>            |               |  there exists s such that r == ++s.
> ---------------------------------------------------------
> r--        | { X tmp = r;  |
>            | --r;          |
>            | return tmp; } |
> ```

> [input.iterators]
>
> ```
> Expression | Operational   | Assertion/note
>            | semantics     | pre-/post-condition
> ---------------------------------------------------------
> ++r        |               | Preconditions:
>            |               |  r is dereferenceable.
> ```

Problem is that the pre-condition is not satisfied.

---

My suggestion for writing the concrete example. This is *slightly* different in that `my_function` will be called before elements are actually removed from the list:

```
list.remove_if([](int n) {
    if ( X + Y == W )
    {
        my_function( Y );
        return X || Y && Z;
    }
    return true;
});
```

If the exact behaviour is needed, then you can use following which isn't quite as pretty:

```
for (auto it = list.begin(), last = list.end(); it != last;)
{
    auto next = it;
    ++next;
    
    if ( X + Y == W )
    {
        if ( X || Y && Z )
        {
            list.erase( it );
        }
        my_function( Y );
    }
    else
    {
        list.erase( it );
    }
    
    it = next;
}
```

Comment: The behavior of `--list.begin()` is almost certainly undefined, but the compiler may do something sensible with it just to make debugging easier.  Totally up to the compiler vendor.

Comment: @Hi-IloveSO What if that is the last remaining element? Then `i--` would go past the beginning of the range.

Comment: @eerorika Think about it again; it never actually would. If `i` was the first element, `list.erase( i++ );` would erase that and `i` would become the next element, at most `list.end()`, and `i--` would backstep as to allow `i++` in the third `for-loop` expression just fine.

Comment: @Hi-IloveSO if you erase the last element, `i == end() == begin()`.  `i--` when `i == begin()` is undefined.

Comment: End can never equal begin. And also, i++ is *post*-increment.

Comment: @Hi-IloveSO `End can never equal begin` Your assumption is wrong. End always equals begin when the list is empty. Which happens when you erase the last remaining element.

Answer (score 3):

The current MSVC C++ standard library implements `std::list` as a circular doubly linked list, with an extra node acting as a coupler between the first and last element.

So `--list.begin() == list.end()` does hold true.

But note that the behaviour of `--list.begin()` is undefined, which is why this particular implementation is a possible choice.

Comment: "does hold true" if you disable checking.

Comment: @MarcGlisse: Yes quite possibly. Having a quick look at the source, it looks like they use an extra node, and stumbling on that in reverse fails the iterator check. Rather clever really.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_node if you want a name for this extra node.